# Getting string length won't work

Tags: c#, string

I'm using below code to find out what is the length of a given string:

```
string foo = "Welcome to stack overflow";
int strlen;

for (int i=0; i<foo.length; strlen++){}

Console.WriteLine(strlen.ToString());
```

But the code never leaves the loop.

Comment: because you are doing `strlen++`, i.e. `i` never changes. you need to do `i++` in the `for` loop

Comment: Why not use `foo.Length`?

Comment: What's wrong with `int strlen = foo.Length;` anyway?

Comment: That's some neat coding style really

Comment: Note that `foo.length` won't even compile, because C# is case-sensitive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, that's weird.

I don't understand your logic, you already have the string length, why use a loop to apply it to another int?

But, well, who am I to judge?

The problem on your loop is that you're not increasing the value of `i`.
Do this instead:

```
for (int i=0; i<foo.Length; i++)
{
     strlen++;
}
```

You could remove the loop and do this to your code:

```
string foo = "Welcome to stack overflow";

Console.WriteLine("String length: " + foo.Length.ToString());
```

**Edit:**

As mentioned in the comments:

> the length property must have it's first letter uppercased, since C# is case sensitive. **- Jon Skeet**

Comment: oh this did work. Thank you! Why can't I use the for loop?

Comment: Well, you CAN use it, but it's not viable since you're using more performance than needed over simply applying the already existing value to the variable.

Answer (score 1):

You are never increasing "i" so the "i < foo.length" will always be true

Answer (score 1):

You should iterate over `i`, not over `strlen`:

```
for (int i=0; i<foo.length; i++){}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have one *typo* (`foo.Length`, not `foo.length`) and two *errors*:

1. Do not forget to assign `0` on local variabale declaration (`int strlen = 0`)
2. Do not forget to increment counter (`i++`)

Something like that:

```
string foo = "Welcome to stack overflow";

// error: assign 0 to strlen
int strlen = 0;

// Typo: foo.Length instead of foo.length
// error: do not forget to increment "i" as well as "strlen"
for (int i = 0; i < foo.Length; strlen++, i++) {}

// 25
Console.WriteLine(strlen.ToString());
```

Test:

```
// 25
Console.WriteLine(foo.Length);
```